# How can i use an JSON or SOAP attribute into a Path URL Param or a Query Param WSO2 Entrerprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm pretty new on WSO2 IE and I'm trying to use a SOAP request to call a REST API.
This first part is OK but one of my API's needs to receive an attribute into its PATH or QUERY parameters. The attribute is sent by the soap call in it's body.

The question is, how can i get this body attribute and pass it in the PATH/QUERY param of the URL dynamically before i send it?

[Picture of my architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRLzO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to construct a dynamic URL. This can be easily done with the ESB Server. Here we have different options to construct this dynamic URL. Following is a sample proxy service that was created to achieve this.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="sample_proxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$body//target" name="Target endpoint"/>
         </log>
         <property name="uri.var.host" value="http://localhost:8280"/>
         <property name="uri.var.context" value="services"/>
         <property expression="$body//target" name="uri.var.resourcepath"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET"
                     uri-template="{uri.var.host}/{uri.var.context}/{uri.var.resourcepath}"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

We are sending the following request to this proxy service.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
   <target>sample_path</target>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the above proxy service what we have done is construct the dynamic URL with the parameters from the soap message please refer to the blog post [1] to further clarify regarding dynamic URLs.

Here in order to extract the parameters from the body, we have used XPaths. Please refer to the documentation [2] to further clarify regarding XPaths. We have extracted the value inside the target element and added it to the end of the URL. Thus this will invoke the http://localhost:8280/services/sample_path from the ESB server.

If you are interested in constructing the URL with query parameters you can do that by concatenating the required URL and using an address endpoint [1].

[1]-https://dzone.com/articles/constructing-dynamic-endpoint-urls-in-wso2-esb
[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath#AccessingPropertieswithXPath-$ctx